# Laravel bootstrap a default Guzzle client

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ioc-container, guzzle

I would like to bootstrap a default Guzzle client to connect with Github. Currently I am setting up a default client in a controller like so:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://api.github.com',
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'token ' . $this->getAccessToken()
            ]
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

I am wrapping it with the middleware closure because otherwise the user that is currently logged in is not available yet. `getAccessToken` needs an `Auth::user`.

How would I rewrite this to a generic re-usable client though? Judging by the documentation from Laravel a good idea might be to bind a `GithubGuzzleClient` into the container through a `ServiceProvider`:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers#writing-service-providers

It seems like `ServiceProviders` are bound into the container before the middleware is even run though. So how would I set up a generic `ServiceProvider` that can also access the logged in user to set the proper `Authorization` header on the freshly instantiated client?

**Edit**

After some reviewing of the documentatoin it seems it can only be done through middleware. I guess it would be viable to create a middleware  which injects a pre-configured `Guzzle` client since at this point I should have the `Auth::user` if my custom middleware runs last in the chain.

It would even be nice to create a middleware group for all routes which need this `Guzzle` instance which has been predefined for Github API calls.

If anybody knows a better way, please let me know.

Comment: try using a composer

Comment: @madalinivascu using view composer like this: `View::composer('*', function ($view) {})` will kill my performance since it will register for views and includes. Setting it for specific pages it also not flexible.

Comment: create a controller, put your code in the constructor, use that controller to extend your desired controllers